# Categorical characterisation of fields and groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, field-theory, monoidal-categories, enriched-category-theory

Given a monoidal category $\mathcal{V}$, is there a categorical characterisation of an object in $\mathcal{V}$ such that it is a group if $\mathcal{V} = Set$ and a field if $\mathcal{V} = Ab$? Or does anybody know of useful references? This would be much appreciated!

Ofcourse I do not expect it by simple means of extra data as groups cannot be descriped operadically, but rather by universal properties or something similar.

EDIT: As noted in the comments: I am looking for something different than group objects, as they do not encompass fields. So I am looking for some categorical framework in which both can fit.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Any object in $\mathbf{Set}$ can be made into a group.

Comment: @lisyarus Presumably this would be a condition on a monoid in $\mathcal V$.

Comment: @lisyarus I don't fully understand the first comment. I mean it more as Kevin notes: a monoid is an object with an associative multiplication and an unit. However these are extra data on the object. I am looking for (categorical) conditions so that it guarantees a group / a field

Comment: @Lilolance For some reason I interpreted a "categorical characterization" as something that tells you whether a particular object is a group or not. Now I see that (presumably) you mean "some categorical data that defines a group". Sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: Finite product, finite coproduct sketches can classify fields: see Example 4.3 of http://tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/8/n3/8-03abs.html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know there is no such characterization. Groups are, of course, the group objects in $\text{Set}$; to my mind the cleanest way to characterize fields is that they are the [simple objects](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/simple+object) in the category of commutative rings (the ones with no nontrivial quotient objects, where by "quotient object" I mean "[effective epimorphism](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/effective+epimorphism).")

Groups and fields are just not actually that analogous. Fields are required to be commutative and inverses are only defined for nonzero elements, so they aren't actually "algebraic." And there's no way to talk about group objects in a monoidal category that isn't cartesian; the closest you get is talking about [Hopf algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_algebra), which are very different from fields.

Answer (score 1):

For groups, it's quite doable: a group object in a cartesian monoidal category is a particular kind of monoid. Now every object in a cartesian monoidal category is canonically a comonoid, where the comultiplication is the diagonal $\Delta:G\to G\times G$ and the counit is the unique map $!:G\to 1$. In fact if $G$ is a monoid, then this comonoid structure makes it a bimonoid, because $\Delta$ and $!$ are always monoid homomorphisms.

This suggests that we want to think about a kind of bimonoid, in a general symmetric monoidal category (the symmetry is necessary to make the tensor product of monoids a monoid.) So let $G$ in $\mathcal V$ be a bimonoid, equipped with a comultiplication $\Delta:G\to G\otimes G$ and a counit $\epsilon:G\to I$ as well as a multiplication $\mu$ and unit $\eta$. Then we can write down the inverse axiom as for a group: introduce an endomorphism $s:G\to G$ (called in this context an "antipode"), such that $\mu\circ(1\otimes s)\circ \Delta=\eta\circ \epsilon$. This is the definition of a *Hopf monoid*, and uniqueness of comonoid structures in Cartesian monoidal categories implies that a Hopf monoid in Sets is precisely a group.

I'm not so sure what to do about fields, since these aren't even algebraically defined--note that we need the notion of the complement of zero to get a field, so they naturally fit in something closer to a topos rather than in a monoidal category.

Comment: Thanks Kevin for this clear explanation, but I already had a look at group objects and hopf-structures, and it is not what I'm looking for. I am explicitely looking for field-structures and I do not at all expect a characterisation with extra data as you give here. In what sense do you think about a topos? maybe this could be a lead

Comment: @Lilolance That would've been helpful to mention, as what you said indicated that you didn't think this could be done even for groups. You certainly won't get an answer that works simultaneously for groups and for fields, as they're just not the same kind of thing. Toposes are the most common kind of categories in which the family of subobjects has a Heyting algebra structure, so that you can talk in particular about the complement of a subobject. Fields have an inverse that's only  defined on the complement of the additive unit.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion. I will edit the question. I still don't think groups and fields are completely different things and I am looking for a context in which I can treat them simultaneously or at least have a source where someone pursued this and gives a mathematical reason for "they're just not the same thing".

Comment: @Lilolance The fact that the inverse on a field is not totally defined is already a very important mathematical reason why fields are not to abelian groups as groups are to sets. For instance, it implies the category of fields is not locally presentable, or in much the same way that the logical theory of fields is not an algebraic theory.

Comment: Yes, I also know this, and this is also the reason why I do not expect extra data (i.e. morphisms) as I mention. It just means I do not need to look into the framework of algebraic theories. That is why I would expect more along the lines of universal properties.

Comment: @Lilolance OK. I don't see what kind of universal properties you might be expecting, so it seems a little vague, but who knows, maybe somebody else will have an idea.